oVirt Managed Block Storage size is N/A
I created pool in Ceph and added this pool in oVirt like manage block storage .
But oVirt doesn't get the size of  manage block storage. Why?


please don't post images of text https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text

You'd better answer the question.
